# On this definition of holding

Tags: phrase-meaning, definition, error

> A tenure; a farm or other estate *held of another*.

The above is the third definition of *holding* in [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/holding) dictionary.

I couldn't make sense of the part in italics, especially on their use of *held*; is it a past participle? And shouldn't it be *by* (instead of *of*)?

Comment: A farm held of another is a farm held (occupied, used) by one person (the tenant) but owned by another person (the owner or landlord).

Comment: But then is the use of the preposition *of* above correct; shouldn't it be *for*? Or is *held of* an idiomatic construction (research about this expression have turned nothing)?

Comment: It is a legal usage

Comment: Somewhat archaic, as are many legal usages.